# How to get live scores through a plugin for openfire?

Tags: ios, xmpp

I want to create a new plugin which will send live scores to the xmpp iOS client.

I have already created a new plugin and a service for it, but not getting any idea how to send  live scores from openfire server to the xmpp iOS client.

Pls, suggest me something.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a plugin?  Why doesn't your service just send it to the client as a message?  You should probably add some details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use multi chat. You can create a room for each match. Anyone who wishes to receive live score (or anything for that matter) joins the room. You have a bot that sends the score into the room and everybody who is in the room gets it. You can also configure the room so that it is visitors only and anonymous. See [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html)

Another way is the use pubsub. Again every match is a node. Users subscribe to the node. See [XEP-0060](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html)

I'm not sure about others XMPP servers but IFAIK MUC and pubsub are supported by [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).